# Should I have my Mac on until "external" hard drive encryption process is done?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, encryption, hdd

I have a MBP 2012 and replaced the internal hard drive with an SSD and the SuperDrive with a 1TB HDD. I'm encrypting my 1TB HDD.

Should I leave my Mac on until it's done?

Does OS X pause the encryption process if I turn my Mac off (or put to sleep) or does it start over every time I turn it back on?

I'm running El Capitan 10.11.5.

Comment: I can't answer specifically however I'd leave it on until the encryption is done. Is there any reason why you can't leave it on until the encryption is done?

Comment: You should probably leave it on until it's done, if it's not too much of an inconvenience. OS X should handle intermittent encryption just fine, but if it's possible leave it on. It shouldn't take too long, unless you have the HDD filled close to capacity.

Comment: It was around 550 GB so it was definitely going to take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily.

OS X seems to handle well pausing and restarting where the encrypting process left off.

However, there is no way I can recommend doing this. I had backups of my data and decided to try it. :) I just wish there was more official information regarding this process.